# How to add to gridcontrol a new row at every click

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, devexpress

I want to add new row to gridcontrol at every button click. I tried many ways but no success. I am sending my code.

```
 private void B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
   Button bt = (Button)sender;
       int productId = (int)bt.Tag;
       AddProductDataContext db = new AddProductDataContext();
       decimal Quantity;
       decimal.TryParse(txtCalculator.Text, out Quantity);
     var results  = from inv in db.Inventories
                                          where inv.RecId == productId
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              inventoryName = inv.InventoryName,
                                              Quantity,
                                              Total = Quantity * inv.InventoryPrice
                                          };

               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
               dt.Columns.Add("inventoryName");
               dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
               dt.Columns.Add("Total");

               foreach (var x in results)
               {
                   DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                   newRow.SetField("inventoryName", x.inventoryName);
                   newRow.SetField("Quantity", x.Quantity);

                   newRow.SetField("Total", x.Total);

               }

               gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
               gridView1.AddNewRow();
}
```

Comment: First you are using my code in your first qustion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187344/how-can-i-add-a-new-row-to-datagrid-at-every-button-click-in-winform

Comment: add gridControl1.DataBind() after   gridControl1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: You must change gridControl1.DataSource = dt; to gridView1.DataSource = dt; Try agai

Comment: Yes you are rigth, I used your code as I didnt know how to edit code section.

Comment: There is no DataBind() option for gridControl and gridview doesnt take DataSource as it is readonly.

Answer (score 0):

You got to call

```
gridView1.DataBind();
```

after you set the DataSource

Comment: Devexpress grid doesnt allow DataBind, so it is not workable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to add a new row in your GridControl :

```
gridView1.AddNewRow();

int rowHandle = gridView1.GetRowHandle(gridView1.DataRowCount);
if (gridView1.IsNewItemRow(rowHandle))
{
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView1.Columns["ColumnName1"], val1);
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView1.Columns["ColumnName2"], val2);
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView1.Columns["ColumnName3"], val3);
}
```

You must change columns name and val1, val2, val3 with your values.

Comment: Yes, this is for devexpress, but you use a GridControl of DevExpress ?

Comment: what's the probleme in your code in question ? you have the error ?

Comment: I solved the problem and posted the solution. Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: Good! i'am glad to hear it :)